# Why can sudo apt-get update find the ros repositories for groovy?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why can sudo apt-get update find the ros repositories for groovy?

I am getting the following error when performing the operation...

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/quanta1/main/binary-amd64/Packages   404   Not found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/quanta1/main/binary-i386/Packages   404   Not found

What should I do?

Somehow, someone put quanta1 instead of quantal in the sources.list.  Someone from Willow Garage should fix that.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51421/why-can-sudo-apt-get-update-find-the-ros-repositories-for-groovy?/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu) look correct. You need to fix the contents of your apt sources.  Usually the default location is in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1